# Does folding glasses increase the probability of separating at the hinge?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science

Please see the images below. I owned these Mykita John glasses for three years, which feels short for glasses to break! Every day, I fold them them before placing it on my night stand and going to bed. Today, when I unfolded them, the left temple just separated.

Now I'm wondering if I folded my glasses too much. If I avoid folding them, will there be less chance of the temple severing at the hinge?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{If I avoid folding them, will there be less chance of the temple severing at the hinge?}$
Yes. In general, the more you fold them, the more "wear and tear" on the eyeglasses, especially at the hinges, but also the rest of the frames. It is precisely the hinge which has failed after eventual use, but the hinges should be able to withstand many more open/close cycles.

P.S. Physics SE is probably not the right place for this question